# values of webpack.resolve.byDependency?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, package, config

Webpack has very little documentation about this property `byDependency`, as seen here [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvebydependency). It says that "typical values are 'esm', 'commonjs', and 'url'.

I'm trying to map out the values, here is what I got so far:

- `'esm'` - triggered when using `import x from 'package';` syntax.
- `'commonjs'` - triggered when using `require('package');` syntax.
- `'url'` - triggered when fetching as direct url, usually for assets, when using `url-loader`, etc.

do you know of any more use cases? just list them if you know

Answer (score 1):

The `resolve.byDependency` object provides extra resolve options per dependency category. Following are the module formats that are mostly commonly used.

- `'esm'`
- `'commonjs'`
- `'amd'`
- `'umd'`
- `'iife'`
- `'url'`

Comment: thanks. any idea on what triggers them? ie how does it know a package was consumed by amd and not umd?